# how to make vim's commands silent when editing remote file

Tags: vim, scp

When I edit a remote file using `e scp://...` command, I need to press any key after each command and this frustrates me.

For example, when I hit `w` to save the file, the message "press enter or type command to continue" shows up. I do not want to see any message after any successful command.

I tried to map commands to make them silent but it did not work.

Answer (score 11):

The netrw plugin has a [lot of settings](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pi_netrw.html#netrw-variables).  The one you're looking for is:

`let g:netrw_silent=1`

Comment: That's exactly what it takes. Note that setting it during the session doesn't have effect: it should be set earlier (e.g. in the `.vimrc`).

Answer (score 3):

This should be directed to the *netrw* (which provides the remote editing functionality) plugin's author. (Dr. Chip's email address can be found in the `:help pi_netrw` documentation.)

There's a fine balance between thwarting *all* output (e.g. via `:silent!`; but then users would complain that there's no troubleshooting information on error) and showing the used commands (which may result in the usability nuisance of the *hit-enter* prompt you've observed). I guess because of the rather high likelihood of problems with remote file access, the plugin author favored the latter.

You can try to moderate the problem e.g. by increasing the `'cmdheight'` option (to 2 or more).

Comment: setting cmdheight to 2 worked for me, although it is not a neat solution. thank you.